# Arabic/Persian file names of a fat32 file system displayed as question mark

Tags: raspbian, filesystem, locale

The Arabic/Persian names of files that created on a fat32 file system flash drive,in windows, displayed as question marks in Raspbian.

Ubuntu has no problem with fat32 name encoding. So the question is that what package(s) or configuration(s) Ubuntu have that enables it to decode those Arabic/Persian names on a fat32 drive?

How can we enable this functionality in Raspbian?